# Javascript: Height reduces on multiple clicks ?

Tags: javascript, height

tried animating a dropdown,worked.But,the height of the element reduces if i keep clicking on it -- finally becomes 0px !!.. not sure why this is happening.

HeightChangePersist -- funciton to increase the height(via steps -- works fine)

when you click on `click here!!`,it works fine the 1st time but clicking on it more times reduces the height(gradually) -- unexpected and unwanted -- please do tell me where i'm going wrong!!..

Kindly help,javascript beginner.

Here's the code --

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.box{
width: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
color: white;
margin-top: 2px;
}
.hide{
display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function heightChangePersist(elem,startHeight,endHeight,steps,intervals,powr) {

    if (elem.heightChangePersist) window.clearInterval(elem.heightChangePersist);

    var currStep = 0;

    elem.heightChangePersist = window.setInterval(

        function() {

            elem.currHeight = easeInOut(startHeight,endHeight,steps,currStep,powr);

            elem.style.height = elem.currHeight+"px";

            currStep++;

            if (currStep > steps) window.clearInterval(elem.heightChangePersist);

        }

        ,intervals)

}
function easeInOut(minValue,maxValue,totalSteps,currStep,powr) {

var delta = maxValue - minValue;

    var stepp = minValue+(Math.pow(((1 / totalSteps)*currStep),powr)*delta);

    return Math.ceil(stepp);

}
function invoke(){

var box1=document. getElementById('box1');
var box2=document. getElementById('box2');

box1.style.display='block';
box2.style.display='block';
heightChangePersist(box1,0,box1.offsetHeight,30,30,.5);
heightChangePersist(box2,0,box2.offsetHeight,30,30,.5);

}
</script>
<div class="box" onclick="invoke()">
click Here!!
</div>
<div id="box2" class="box hide">
This is a test done to check the animation of a particular item.Hoping it works and i hope to be successful in this trial..!!
</div>
<div id="box1" class="box hide">
This is a test done to check the animation of a particular 
item.Hoping it works and i hope to be successful in this trial..!!This is a test done 
to check the animation of a particular item.Hoping it works and i hope to be successful in this trial
..!!This is a test done to check the animation of a particular item.Hoping it works
 and i hope to be successful in this trial..!!
</div>
```

The heightChangePersist -- Something which i picked up from http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=javascriptanimation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it call all the times you click 'click me' the event invoke. So it can't finish the interval and then the animation.
If you disable it before start your animation and re-enable it when animation is over it works :)

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.box{
width: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
color: white;
margin-top: 2px;
}
.hide{
display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function heightChangePersist(elem,startHeight,endHeight,steps,intervals,powr) {

    if (elem.heightChangePersist) window.clearInterval(elem.heightChangePersist);

    var currStep = 0;

    var a = document.getElementById('button');
    a.onclick = null;
    elem.heightChangePersist = window.setInterval(

        function() {

            elem.currHeight = easeInOut(startHeight,endHeight,steps,currStep,powr);

            elem.style.height = elem.currHeight+"px";

            currStep++;

            if (currStep > steps) {
                window.clearInterval(elem.heightChangePersist);
                a.onclick = function onclick(event) { invoke() };
            }

        }

        ,intervals)

    ;

}
function easeInOut(minValue,maxValue,totalSteps,currStep,powr) {

var delta = maxValue - minValue;

    var stepp = minValue+(Math.pow(((1 / totalSteps)*currStep),powr)*delta);

    return Math.ceil(stepp);

}
function invoke(){

var box1=document. getElementById('box1');
var box2=document. getElementById('box2');

box1.style.display='block';
box2.style.display='block';
heightChangePersist(box1,0,box1.offsetHeight,30,30,.5);
heightChangePersist(box2,0,box2.offsetHeight,30,30,.5);

}

</script>
<div id="button" class="box" onclick="invoke()">
click Here!!
</div>
<div id="box2" class="box hide">
This is a test done to check the animation of a particular item.Hoping it works and i hope to be successful in this trial..!!
</div>
<div id="box1" class="box hide">
This is a test done to check the animation of a particular 
item.Hoping it works and i hope to be successful in this trial..!!This is a test done 
to check the animation of a particular item.Hoping it works and i hope to be successful in this trial
..!!This is a test done to check the animation of a particular item.Hoping it works
 and i hope to be successful in this trial..!!
</div>
```

Comment: Y should the height change when u click on it before the other function ends ??

Comment: Yup,As @robby had already mentioned,i should only do it once the previous invoke is finished.But - i'm lost on y the height changes on multiple calls.Either way,thank you for giving me a solution.

Comment: because if the setInterval (and animation) isn't finished your offsetHeight change.

Comment: my solution is better because it doesn't fire the onclick event if isn't necessary. So you'll have better performance and better code :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you called the heightChangePersist function again when the previous heightChangePersist still not completed.

I modified your code, and the problem resolved:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.box{
width: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
color: black;
margin-top: 2px;
}
.hide{
display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function heightChangePersist(elem,startHeight,endHeight,steps,intervals,powr) {


    if (elem.heightChangePersist) window.clearInterval(elem.heightChangePersist);
    var currStep = 0;
    completeFlag++;
    elem.heightChangePersist = window.setInterval(

        function() {

            elem.currHeight = easeInOut(startHeight,endHeight,steps,currStep,powr);

            elem.style.height = elem.currHeight+"px";

            currStep++;

            if (currStep > steps){
                window.clearInterval(elem.heightChangePersist);
                completeFlag--;
            }
        }

        ,intervals)

}
function easeInOut(minValue,maxValue,totalSteps,currStep,powr) {

var delta = maxValue - minValue;

    var stepp = minValue+(Math.pow(((1 / totalSteps)*currStep),powr)*delta);

    return Math.ceil(stepp);

}
var completeFlag = 0;
function invoke(){
if(completeFlag==0){
    var box1=document. getElementById('box1');
    var box2=document. getElementById('box2');

    box1.style.display='block';
    box2.style.display='block';

    heightChangePersist(box1,0,box1.offsetHeight,30,30,.5);
    heightChangePersist(box2,0,box2.offsetHeight,30,30,.5);
}
}
</script>
<div class="box" onclick="invoke()">
click Here!!
</div>
<div id="box2" class="box hide">
This is a test done to check the animation of a particular item.Hoping it works and i hope to be successful in this trial..!!
</div>
<div id="box1" class="box hide">
This is a test done to check the animation of a particular 
item.Hoping it works and i hope to be successful in this trial..!!This is a test done 
to check the animation of a particular item.Hoping it works and i hope to be successful in this trial
..!!This is a test done to check the animation of a particular item.Hoping it works
 and i hope to be successful in this trial..!!
</div>
```

Take note on the completeFlag.

Comment: But,even if the height function was called againg before it got completed,y should the height change??

Comment: And forgot to mention -- Thanks a ton,problem solved yes,but more curious on where i was going wrong ??

Comment: If you called the function before it got completed, the box1.offsetHeight and box2.offsetHeight will be different from the first time